# Bash - extract url from xml file

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have this file (dev1.temp):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<krpano version="1.0.8.15" showerrors="false">

          <include url="include/sa/index.xml" /> <include url="content/sa.xml" />
          <include url="include/global/index.xml" />
          <include url="include/orientation/index.xml" />
          <include url="include/movecamera/index.xml" /> <include url="content/movecamera.xml" />
          <include url="include/fullscreen/index.xml" />
          <include url="include/instructions/index.xml" />
          <include url="include/coordfinder/index.xml" />
          <include url="include/editor_and_options/index.xml" />
</krpano>
```

The goal is to get all the url's content and put them in a temp file (devel.temp). The output would be:

```
include/sa/index.xml
content/sa.xml
include/global/index.xml
include/orientation/index.xml
include/movecamera/index.xml
content/movecamera.xml
include/fullscreen/index.xml
include/instructions/index.xml
include/coordfinder/index.xml
include/editor_and_options/index.xml
```

To do the trick I have the following script:

```
# Make a temp file with all the files url's    
grep -o 'url=['"'"'"][^"'"'"']*['"'"'"]' $temp_folder"/devel1.temp" > $temp_folder"/devel2.temp"
# Strip off everything to leave just the url's'    
sed -e 's/^url=["'"'"']//' -e 's/["'"'"']$//' $temp_folder"/devel2.temp" > $temp_folder"/devel.temp"
```

Yesterday it worked perfectly. Today, devel2.temp and devel.temp output is this:

```
[01;31m[Kurl="include/sa/index.xml"[m[K
[01;31m[Kurl="content/sa.xml"[m[K
[01;31m[Kurl="include/global/index.xml"[m[K
[01;31m[Kurl="include/orientation/index.xml"[m[K
[01;31m[Kurl="include/movecamera/index.xml"[m[K
[01;31m[Kurl="content/movecamera.xml"[m[K
[01;31m[Kurl="include/fullscreen/index.xml"[m[K
[01;31m[Kurl="include/instructions/index.xml"[m[K
[01;31m[Kurl="include/coordfinder/index.xml"[m[K
[01;31m[Kurl="include/editor_and_options/index.xml"[m[K
```

Any ideas about what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like `grep` is using ANSI sequences to colour its output even when the output is not the terminal. Change its `--color` from `always` to `auto`.

Rather than using `grep` to process XML, you should use an XML-aware tool. For example, in [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh), you can write

```
open file.xml ;
perl { use Term::ANSIColor } ;
for /krpano/include
    echo :s { color('bright_yellow') }
            @url
            { color('reset') } ;
```

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer, though. You should not use line-oriented regex tools to manipulate structured formats like XML.

Comment: @tripleee: Better now?

Answer (score 3):

Consider using xml targeted tools, for example xpath. I'd suggest this:

```
xpath -e "/krpano/include/@url" -q yourFile.xml | cut -f 2 -d "=" | sed 's/"//
```

If you're sure that the xml will have `krpano` root with `include`'s only having `url` attribute. You can also use the below for shorthand, but the above will run faster.

```
xpath -e "//@url" -q yourFile.xml | cut -f 2 -d "=" | sed 's/"//
```

Answer (score 2):

In additional to *choroba*'s comment re. your ANSI sequences, I would avoid parsing XML via sed etc. where possible, and look to use an XML-aware scripting tool. I use the [XMLStarlet toolkit](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/). It'll mean your scripts are character-encoding/entity aware and more robust int he face of changing XML.

Answer (score 1):

A third xml aware scripting tool is my [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html):

```
xidel /tmp/your.xml -e //@url
```

(contrary to most it supports XPath 2.0, although that is overkill for this problem)